# SVG image generated in browser different in Illustrator

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator

I'm writing a web application which generates SVG images in the browser.

The SVG's I'm generating work fine in ever browser. However, when I download one of the SVG's and try to open it in Adobe Illsutrator, all the transformations are all over the place.

They are in fact so different that you have to zoom right out to see where the shapes are positioned.

This is the contents of the SVG, you can see it's pretty simple. Just a couple of nested SVG's and a few basic shapes:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="592" height="592" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <svg style="overflow:visible;" x="88.80000305175781" y="88.80000305175781" fill="#777777">
    <svg style="overflow:visible;" height="100px" width="100px">
      <rect width="100" height="100" style="stroke:#006600;" transform="scale(4.144 4.144)"></rect>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <svg style="overflow:visible;" width="592" height="592" x="176.60000000000016" y="177.60000000000014" fill="#000000">
    <rect width="592" height="592" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke="#bbbbbb" transform="scale(0.4 0.4)"></rect>
    <svg style="overflow:visible;" x="-0.0000015258789005656581" y="-0.0000015258789005656581">
      <svg style="overflow:visible;" height="48px" width="48px">
        <ellipse id="SvgjsEllipse1010" rx="24" ry="24" cx="24" cy="24" style="stroke:#006600;fill:#00cc00;" transform="scale(4.933333333333334 4.933333333333334)"></ellipse>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

I don't know the SVG spec inside out, but I'm doing anything particularly complex, so it all seems good to me. I can't see a reason why Illustrator would render it so differently to browsers.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

**Edit**

This is what it looks like in Illsutrator, as you can see the scaling and positioning is all off, the small square in the center is the 592 x 592 canvas area, so you can see who far I am zoomed out.

[image]

Comment: I don't have Illustrator to test it out, but my first suggestion would be to try adding some units (px) to your width and height values on the outermost `<svg>`.

Comment: Good thinking but no cigar, I added px to all the measurement units, it changed but still looks crazy

Comment: Are you able to post a screen shot to help us understand what "crazy" means?  FYI, Inkscape had no problem with the layout (although it didn't like your transparent black fill colour!)

Comment: Well I suppose it's good that it looks ok in Inkscape, maybe I should think again about the transparent black fill...I've added a screenshot of what it looks like anyhow.

Comment: You might try adding a viewBox (http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/Making+Sense+of+SVG+viewBox%27s+Madness), not sure if it would help but it might.

Comment: Is it possible AI doesn't like those extremely long numbers?  What happens if you truncate them to fewer decimal places?

Comment: Or maybe it doesn't like/handle/expect nested `<svg>` elements.  Is there a reason you have to use them?

Comment: @BigBadaboom I don't have to use them, but I am building the final SVG from other SVG's, so the final ones have nested svg's in. As far as I know nested SVG's are allowed in the spec, but maybe it could be causing a problem. I'll have a play and replace them with groups, see if it helps. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @BigBadaboom it looks like you're onto something with the while Illustrator not liking nested SVG elements thing. I replace them with groups, and although it removed some of the transformations, it looked the same in illustrator as in the browser. If you do an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect AI doesn't like/handle/expect nested `<svg>` elements.  Try replacing them with groups.  Those with `x` and `y` attributes may need to have a `transform` added to get it to look the same.  Also if the `overflow` is important, you may need to tweak things further as that property is not valid for group elements.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info overflow/transform with groups.